# Show $f : X \to \mathbb R$ is measurable if $\{x \in X: f(x) \le d\}$ is measurable for all $d \in D$ ($D$ dense)

Tags: measure-theory

I am thinking about the following:  Let $(X, \mathbb X)$ be a measurable space. Let $D$ be a dense subset of $\mathbb R$ and show that $f : X \to \mathbb R$ is measurable if $\{x \in X: f(x) \le d\}$ is measurable for all $d \in D$.

My attempt: $f$ is measurable iff for all $c \in \mathbb R$ we have that $\{x \in X: f(x) > c\} \in \mathbb X$. \
Let $c \in \mathbb R$. Since $D$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, for any $c \in \mathbb R$ there is a sequence $(d_n) \subset D$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} d_n = c$. Hence
\begin{align*}
\{x : f(x) > c\} &= \cup_{n = 1}^\infty \{x: f(x) > d_n, \, d_n \ge c\} \cup \cap_{n = 1}^\infty \{x : f(x) > d_n, \, d_n < c\}.
\end{align*}
I'm quite unsure about this decomposition above. But the problem is that I don't know how to use the convergence of the sequence, since it could be that $d_n > c$ or $d_n \le c$.

Comment: You can choose the sequence $(d_n)$ to be strictly decreasing. Then you can take $\{x : f(x) > c\}= \cup_{n = 1}^\infty\{x: f(x) > d_n, \, d_n >c\}$. Even simpler: $\{x:f(x)>c\}=\cup_{d\in D, d>c}\{x: f(x)>d\}$

Comment: In your decomposition, you get a problem for $f(x) = c$. Because if $d_n$ is strictly increasing, then $x$ belongs to the set on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 1):

Setting  measurability aside for the moment, let's state the following: for any map $f:X\to\mathbb R$ the lower level sets   $L_c=\{x:f(x)\le c\}$,  $c\in\mathbb R$, are determined by the sets $L_d$, $d\in D$. Namely,
$$L_c = \bigcap_{d\in D, \ d\ge c} L_d \tag{1}$$
Indeed, $L_c\subseteq L_d$ for every $d\ge c$. To get the reverse inclusion, suppose $x\notin L_c$. By density of $D$, there is $d\in D$ such that $c<d<f(x)$. Thus $x$ does not belong to the intersection in (1).

Although (1) does not directly give measurability when $D$ is uncountable, you can proceed in two ways: (a) replace $D$ with its  dense countable subset (using the fact  that a subset of a separable space is separable); (b) apply the argument to the subset of $D$  obtained by picking $d_n$, $n\ge 1$, such that $c<d_n<c+1/n$. This subset will not be dense; but it's good enough for the argument to work.

Comment: I like (b) better than (a). In general, a subspace of a separable   space is not necessarily separable. Of course, it is true for the real line.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland I'm pretty sure separability is inherited by subsets. Or perhaps you don't use the axiom of choice?

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics Search for the word "separable".

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Ah, I had metric spaces in mind, while you meant topological.